# Problemas con la instalación de shiny

Tags: r, shiny

¡Buenas!
Estoy intentando instalar el paquete shiny de R, pero me salta el siguiente error:

> ```
> *** arch - i386 Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found ERROR: compilation failed for package 'fastmap'
> * removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/fastmap'
> * installing *source* package 'commonmark' ...
> ** package 'commonmark' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** using staged installation
> ** libs
>
> *** arch - i386 Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found ERROR: compilation failed for package 'commonmark'
> * removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/commonmark'
> * installing *source* package 'glue' ...
> ** package 'glue' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** using staged installation
> ** libs
>
> *** arch - i386 Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found ERROR: compilation failed for package 'glue'
> ```

¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo? ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Pareciera que te esta faltando `Rtools`  o estuviera mal instalado. Descarga e instala la versión que necesites (entiendo por el mensaje, la de 32 bits) desde este enlace: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/, luego vuelve a probar instalar shiny.